# Terminal emulator for Android that supports viewing images?

Tags: x11, window-manager, android, terminal-emulator

I am planning on logging into my unix desktop via an Anroid tablet.  Is there a terminal emulator that will allow me to view images, such as making plots in ipython, via X11 protocol?

Comment: Though it is not supported for the Android OS, [Terminology](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J9DPeEfPzBg) is supported on most Android hardware. You'll need to install a more conventional linux installation to run it and its enlightenment libs on, though - which is easily done, nowadays. Dual-boots are pretty common.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you can run an X server on Android.

For a bare X11 server, see [Play store: X Server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=au.com.darkside.XServer) for example.

That could help with very **special needs**, like showing a plot window on **fixed screen position** with **no window manager** for example.

You could run a full xsession on that display of course, but I think that is not too useful in most general cases.

You would use a normal terminal emulator, and set the display to your X server. (You could run a terminal emulator like `xterm` on the X server of course - but the X11 keyboard simulation will not really be useable.)